# What is zero (deleted) in pmap output?

Tags: linux, memory-management

Whats does the `zero (deleted)` under `Mapping` column mean from the output of `pmap -x pid` command in Linux? How is it different from `anon`? I couldn't find anything from the man page.

```
Address   Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode   Mapping
adf00000     132      36      36 rw---    [ anon ]
adf21000     892       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
ae0ff000       4       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
aea69000     504       0       0 rw-s-  zero (deleted)
aeae7000       4       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
aeae8000    8192      24      24 rw---    [ anon ]
af2e8000   65536   11968       0 rw-s-  apc.eEfjkY (deleted)
b32fd000     236       8       0 r-x--  libxslt.so.1.1.26
b3338000       4       4       4 rw---  libxslt.so.1.1.26
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe that the mappings that are `shared` indicated by the '**s**' under the `mode` column are shown as deleted.
The shared mappings declared by the `MAP_SHARED` flag in the `mmap` call will be shown as deleted in the pmap since the shared memory regions used by processes have to be counted only once.

As for the zero all mappings that are not backed by a file are `zero` initialized. We know that the linux allocates memory only when the data is written to it.

Therefore any region that is **shared** and **uninitialised** (no data written on to it by process) will be accounted by pmap as `zero(deleted)`.

Also i observed that if u remove the `MAP_SHARED` and replace it with say `MAP_PRIVATE` ,

`addr = mmap(NULL,4096,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE,-1,0)`

the zero(deleted) will no longer appear in pmap output.

Comment: From this link (https://techtalk.intersec.com/2013/07/memory-part-2-understanding-process-memory/), it appears that "zero" refers to the fact that the file mapped to that region was an instance of /dev/zero that was subsequently deleted by the kernel - so the name zero (deleted). You can also see this in action if you run an executable (eg:"yourexe"), then delete the underlying file from disk, in which case you'd see yourexe (deleted) in some of the regions